# ¿Como validar que al momento de editar un usuario no se modifique y se guarde uno que ya exista en C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hola buenas estoy intentando validar que al momento de editar un usuario no se ingrese un usuario que ya exista...
tengo un crud de usuarios y en este ya valido que al momento de Guardar no me guarde un usuario existente, y cuando edito un usuario solo doy doble clic al Grid y me manda los datos a los campos de texto, pero la misma funcion al momento de editar me daba error porque obviamente ya existia asi que para la edicion tuve que crear otra función y con esa simplemente dejo pasar que se guarde el usuario actual, el problema es si digamos tengo dos usuarios 1-"Juan21" y 2-"Jose21", no quiero que se pueda cambiar "Juan21" y modificar a "Jose21", ya que al hacerlo, me deja modificarlo y al momento de logearse me logeo como si fuera jose pero los nombres y aplllidos son los de juan, no se si me xplico bien......

El codigo de validacion al guardar es el siguiente:

```
public bool YaExiste(string userName)
    {
        bool existe = false;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Form1.RutaConexion))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=@Username";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", userName);

            existe = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0;

        }
        return existe;
    }
```

y el del boton "editar" era este:

```
public bool PrevenirEdicionUsuario(string userName)
    {
        bool existe = false;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Form1.RutaConexion))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=@Username";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", userName);

            existe = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 1;

        }
        return existe;
    }
```

mi logica era si me da igual a 1 quiere decir que es este mismo usuario y por lo tanto me lo debe dejar pasar, pero se le puede modificar a uno que ya existe y siempre lo deja pasar y aparte se modifica y al momento de logearse me logeo con el usuario al que le modifique, es decir se me borra el usuario anterior...
que podria estar pasando? de antemano gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas modificar tu tabla en la base de datos. Cualquier validación que intentes hacer será más costosa y menos efectiva que la definición de la tabla. Solo crea un constraint de la siguiente manera.

```
ALTER TABLE Usuarios ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_UserNAme  UNIQUE (userName);
```

Con eso, puedes capturar el error que generará al tratar de generar un valor duplicado, ya sea por inserción o actualización.

Comment: Te amo! gracias

Comment: Y así nació el amor.